# Excel formula for analyzing one column against others in a somewhat complex way?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I created/manage a SQL database that stores schedules and standings data from a youth sports program, which is then accessed and updated through their website for public display.

When a new season begins, I get a master Excel spreadsheet with all of the game info for that season - we're talking several hundred games.  I then sort and organize the spreadsheet to match the format of the SQL tables it will be broken up and imported into.  It's a time consuming process, but it works well enough on its own.  There's only one thing I consider a big headache:

Several years ago, I discovered that it was helpful to apply a separate ID column to the spreadsheet/tables, so each individual game is coded with its own unique ID.  That way, when a game's date is added or changed later in the season, the only change that needs to be made within the database is to that value in order for it to sort properly.  Hopefully, that makes sense.

So, basically, a specific row in a specific division (one game) lists the date as September 28, 2017.  The unique ID assigned to that game is then "92801".  If there's another game on the same day, it gets assigned "92802", etc.  However, I have to manually input this for each row and there are hundreds.

Is there some sort of formula that could be applied which takes the data from the date column, checks if there are any other matching dates in that division, and assigns an appropriate ID in the format shown above?  This would make things SO much easier.  May be wishful thinking.  Appreciate any insight or advice.

Comment: Yes, there is. Try a combination of TEXT and COUNTIF. Edit your question to show what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. If you cannot solve it, please read the Help topics: [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and, especially, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Thanks for your input.  I recognize that I asked the question in a bit of a convoluted way, in this case.  I was able to use the TEXT formula, which I was unaware of, to create a partial solution.  Will look into it further next season.  Thanks, again.